# how to configure tomcat 6 on eclipse?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, tomcat

[image: apache tomacat installed path][image: server selecting] [image: tomcat install][image: with out any server in my eclips juno![ nothing coming while selecting tomcat 6][image: without server]!

I have installed tomcat6 successfully,how to configure tomcat on eclipse.
what's wrong in my eclipse please suggest me..!

Answer (score 0):

You first have to add your tomcat installation directory  in  `Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments`. After this you can select the tomcat installation in the `New Server` dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

open **window->preferences->servers->runtime environment->Add->select apache version->select apache home directory->finish.**

Comment: see my edit in my question..i done what u told but still same problem

Comment: which tomcat version you are using and up to which extent you are giving installation path?

Comment: I WILL GIVE YOU HOW TO INSTALL TOMCAT 6

Comment: `1.  cd /home/mpatil/Downloads/
 2. tar zxvf apache-tomcat-6.0.37.tar.gz
 3. cd apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin
 4. ./startup.sh 
 5. tail -f /home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/logs/catalina.out`

Comment: what asking after you create a new server

Comment: tomcat6 i select but nothing coming in server name thats the my problem

Comment: are you mention in new server window??  have you select your tomcat version from that list??

Comment: YA i mentioned and selected tomcat6 but after selecting sername nothing coming?

Comment: can you send that snapshot and your installed server path?

Comment: home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37 this is my installed path i edit my question with snapshots

Comment: hello @subash replay me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40824/discussion-between-subash-and-ram)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure you tomcat server in eclipse, by following steps

1. Click on Servers in the bottom panel of eclipse and then click new.
2. In the list of servers select tomcat and then select version and click next.
3. Give your installation of tomcat in Tomcat installation directory.
4. click finish

Comment: see my edit in my question..i done what u told but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

You could fid the step by step instructions on the following URL. Hope this helps :

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Configuring_an_Application_Server_in_Eclipse.pdf